# How can I fix this six-sided dice class?

Tags: java, dice

I'm trying to create a Craps game that rolls two six-sided dice using the Dice class below. The issue is, however, that some of the rolls are greater than 6 which ruins the entire functionality of the game. Here is an output example of what I'm talking about:
Come out roll is (3)(12) sum is 15
Enter point Round with Point Value = 15
Roll is (10)(8) with sum 18
Roll is (9)(3) with sum 12
Roll is (4)(5) with sum 9
Roll is (8)(7) with sum 15
Pass Line bet wins 5

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
    private int numDice;
    private int numSides;
    private Random random;

    public Dice(int numDice, int numSides) {
        this.numDice = numDice;
        this.numSides = numSides;
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public int roll() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
            total += random.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Code I'm using in game class from Dice class:

```
public Game() {
        ## filler
        dice = new Dice(2, 6);
    }

int roll1 = dice.roll();
        int roll2 = dice.roll();
        int sum = roll1 + roll2;
        System.out.println("Come out roll is (" + roll1 + ")(" + roll2 + ") sum is " + sum);
```

I have to roll two dice for the game. It seems like the two rolls are being added together in the Dice class? I'm not sure.

Comment: why would a `Dice` be comprised of more than one dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Dice` class already includes the functionality to roll the same dice multiple times and return the sum.

```
dice = new Dice(2, 6);
```

Here you define that `dice` should consist of two dice rolls.
When you run

```
int roll1 = dice.roll();
```

it will generate two random numbers and return the sum of them.

If you want to *manually* roll the same single dice multiple times you need to change the constructor call:

```
dice = Dice(1,6)
```